# Authlogic multiple passwords per resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic to password protect particular routes. The user is able to share certain pages, and can protect them with a password. I have this working fine for one password, but want to be able to let users have multiple passwords for the same pages.

I want to keep it simple, and not resort to a full username and password. The goal is for simple protection of content via a password.

I know I can override the login method, but it is expecting one object to be returned, and the verify password method is expecting to evaluate one value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would just write my own authentication

Comment: I agree with this; I see no reason to use authlogic for what you describe.

Comment: I was just trying to use a solution to get the salting and such for free. Point taken - will roll my own. Thanks!

Comment: +1 This is a legitimate question, even if the answer is not what the author was hoping.